# Combining Latitude Longitude Data to make Polar Stereographic Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotting, seaborn, plotly

I have two 896 row x 608 column pandas dataframes representing latitude and longitude positions of a polar stereographic grid.

Combining these seems easy enough to make a single table, but I'm not sure if a single grid is the right way forward for plotting (although I assume it is - e.g. if I want to plot total precipitation that's on this 896x608 grid I assume this is the reference).

What's a way to take this information and make a polar stereographic plot out of it?